# OR-tools: Adding a dimension based on the accumulation of another dimension in python (specifically vehicle costs for every 24 hours used)

Tags: python, routes, or-tools

I want to add a constant cost for each 24 hours that a vehicle is in use (using the python version of OR-tools). I have no clue how to approach this though.

Answer (score 1):

I received an idea for a solution to this from James E. Marca (link: https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/zEZ8PaMsV6g/m/W5KwdQN3AAAJ)

"You can't use dependent dimensions in python, as you discovered.

I would suggest creating an explicit daily cost dimension. Regular
nodes add zero to the cost dimension, but create a dummy "end-of-day"
node, one per day per vehicle, that adds your daily cost. So handle
this logic in the callback function (check node type, if not an
end-of-day-node, return zero, otherwise return the daily cost).

Then add all the end of day nodes to the solver's minimization by
using a call to
routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(daily_cost_dimension.CumulVar(day_i_vehicle_j_index))

Maybe that points you in the right direction?"

[Later message]

I was just thinking about point 1. I don't think you need to use an
extra cost dimension, but rather can just merge with whatever you're
already having the model minimize (distance or time).

What I mean is create the daily node as I described (one per vehicle
per day), allow them to be dropped (disjunction of zero) but require
them to be visited if the time dimension for a vehicle is greater than
a multiple of 24 hours. Then make the distance to the daily node
equal to the extra cost per day that you want to incur.

So for example, in the standard examples, you have this:

```
    def create_data_model():
"""Stores the data for the problem."""
data = {}
data['distance_matrix'] = [
...
# set distance from all nodes to dummy end-of-day nodes as daily cost
]

...

# Instantiate the data problem.
data = create_data_model()

def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
"""Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
# Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
#
# this next line will correctly add "cost" of visiting end-of-day nodes
# if the data was set up correctly earlier
#
return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
```